# How to properly register HiddenHttpMethodFilter in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I am following a tutorial that has the following registration code for HiddenHttpMethodFilter. It uses a @Bean annotation that returns a new instance:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactiveWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
        return new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me? I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="/images/Picture of me 1.png" ><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

and the request handler:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = BASE_PATH + "/" + FILENAME)
public Mono<String> deleteFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
    return imageService.deleteImage(filename).then(Mono.just("redirect:/"));
}
```

But the server does not redirect the POST request to my deleteFile method:

```
2018-06-18 10:47:59.486  WARN 16344 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [POST http://localhost:8080/images/Picture%20of%20me%201.png]: Response status 405 with reason "Request method 'POST' not supported"
```

If I change the @DeleteMapping to @PostMapping, then it works, which leads me to suspect that the HiddenHttpMethodFilter is not kicking in?

Answer (score 2):

ok, finally figured it out. Turns out there are two possible imports:

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
```

or

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
```

and I was choosing the wrong (2nd one). I guess when developing a reactive web project you need to import the first one. I wish they had named the classes differently. Posting this answer in case somebody else falls into the same trap.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Boot the [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) could be enabled using `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled` property:

> spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled
>
> false
>
> Whether to enable Spring's HiddenHttpMethodFilter.

Add it to `application.properties`/`yaml` file and set it to `true`:
`spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true`

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)